# Scala/JOGL error in Eclipse: Missing Dependencies while loading X (GLCanvas etc.)

Tags: eclipse, scala, jogl

I am trying to use JOGL with Scala in Eclipse, but being a JOGL/Scala neophyte, have run into some dependency errors which I cannot make any heads or tails of. Googling hasn't returned much of anything useful.

I have set up a Java JOGL project as per
[Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE](http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE#Eclipse_IDE_project).

Compiling the following Java class in a Java project that depends on the above project

```
import javax.media.opengl.GLProfile;
import javax.media.opengl.GLCapabilities;
import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GLProfile glp = GLProfile.getDefault();
        GLCapabilities caps = new GLCapabilities(glp);
        GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas(caps);

        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

works, and outputs `Hello World` as expected.

However, making a Scala project and trying to use the JOGL project as follows

```
import javax.media.opengl.GLProfile;
import javax.media.opengl.GLCapabilities;
import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;


object Game {
    def main (args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val glp = GLProfile.getDefault();
        val caps = new GLCapabilities(glp);
        val canvas : GLCanvas = new GLCanvas(caps);

        System.out.println("Hello World"); 
    }
}
```

won't even compile, as Eclipse informs me of the following errors:

> error while loading CapabilitiesImmutable, Missing dependency 'class com.jogamp.common.type.WriteCloneable', required by G:\Eclipse\workspace\JOGL\jogl-all.jar(javax/media/nativewindow/CapabilitiesImmutable.class)  Scala JOGL      Unknown Scala Problem
>
> error while loading GLCanvas, Missing dependency 'class com.jogamp.common.util.locks.RecursiveLock', required by G:\Eclipse\workspace\JOGL\jogl-all.jar(javax/media/opengl/awt/GLCanvas.class) Scala JOGL      Unknown Scala Problem
>
> error while loading GLContext, Missing dependency 'class 
>   com.jogamp.common.util.locks.RecursiveLock', required by G:\Eclipse\workspace\JOGL\jogl-all.jar(javax/media/opengl/GLContext.class) Scala JOGL      Unknown Scala Problem

Removing the lines pertaining to `GLCapabilities` and `GLCanvas`, giving

```
object Game {
    def main (args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val glp = GLProfile.getDefault();


        System.out.println("Hello World"); 
    }
}
```

does compile and print `Hello World`.

My questions are - Why doesn't the Scala code work, and what can I do to fix it? Am I doing some crazy voodoo mixing up JOGL and Scala code that I shouldn't be doing? Did I forget to add some dependencies?

**Version Information**

Eclipse: (Version: **Juno Release Build id: 20120614-1722**)

Scala IDE for Eclipse: (Version:   **2.1.0.nightly-2_09-201208290312-cc63a95**)
                       (Provider:  **scala-ide.org**)

JOGL as part of JOGAMP **Release 2.0-rc10**

Edit:
Ok, adding the gluegen-rt.jar and jogl.jar libraries to the build path in the Scala project itself solves this issue (I can't believe I didn't think of doing that first .. ). I'm still not exactly sure what I was doing wrong though.

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference, in one of my JOGL SBT projects, I needed to add:

- gluegen-rt.jar
- gluegen-rt-natives-.jar
- jogl-all-2.0-rc9.jar
- jogl-all-2.0-rc9-natives-.jar

to the list of dependencies in order for this to work. My guess is that you have to include these on the build path in Eclipse.

These are available from this repository: http://jogamp.org/deployment/maven